# Aligning Matching cells in excel (vbs, macro)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

**Update (new problem)**
This code automatically isolates those without matches. But, Is there any way I could Isolate those that match?

---

**TL;DR Version**
So, basically, below is a code for matching cells in excel but it doesn't match 
everything even though some of them actually do match
Here's a sample what happens:

```
          A        B
....
2383           一時間
....
25498    一時間
```

when it should be something like

```
          A        B
....
2383      一時間   一時間
```

---

**Details:**

http://www.mediafire.com/download/q7ym8qb41ywri0c/Soverflow.txt
Attached is a tab delimited text for import into excel.

So, I was looking for a solution for aligning matching cells in columns, but in addition to that, it should also align the other cells in a row together with what was moved. I'm going to use the cells **without** any matches for my own purposes

It works for some cells, but it doesn't work for other cells so I thought there must be something the code isn't doing.

For example, if you run the code you'll see that at cell `B2383`, there's `一時間` but if you CTRL+F for other matches, you'll find it again at cell `A25498`. They should have been aligned like the other matches but for some odd reason, it didn't.

Am I using macros the wrong way? I simply copy-pasted the code into Developer>Macros>Create>Alt+Q, then I ran it.

```
Sub test() 
    Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, w, x, n As Long 
    With Range("a3").CurrentRegion 
        a = .Value 
        .ClearContents 
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
            For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1) 
                If a(i, 1) <> "" Then 
                    If Not .exists(a(i, 1)) Then 
                        Redim w(1 To UBound(a, 2)) 
                        w(1) = a(i, 1): .Item(a(i, 1)) = w 
                    End If 
                End If 
            Next 
            For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1) 
                If a(i, 2) <> "" Then 
                    If Not .exists(a(i, 2)) Then 
                        Redim w(1 To UBound(a, 2)) 
                    Else 
                        w = .Item(a(i, 2)) 
                    End If 
                    For ii = 2 To UBound(a, 2) 
                        w(ii) = a(i, ii) 
                    Next 
                    .Item(a(i, 2)) = w 
                End If 
            Next 
            x = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.items)) 
            n = .Count 
        End With 
        .Resize(n).Value = x 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Credits to the guy who made the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current region at the beginning of the code is not accurate.
[image]
[image]

Delete the blank row and see how things change.

Comment: Btw, this code automatically isolates those without matches. But, Is there any way I could Isolate those that match? Thanks.